# Is there an easier way to change the index values of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reindex

I am taking a dataframe, breaking it into two dataframes, and then I need to change the index values so that no number is greater than the total number of rows.

Here's the code:

```
dataset =   pd.read_csv("dataset.csv",usecols['row_id','x','y','time'],index_col=0)
splitvalue = math.floor((0.9)*786239)
train = dataset[dataset.time < splitvalue]
test = dataset[dataset.time >= splitvalue]
```

Here's the change that I am doing.  I am wondering if there is an easier way:

```
test.index=range(test.shape[0])
test.index.rename('row_id',inplace=True)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
test = test.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis('row_id')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should shuffle your data before slicing....

```
dataset.reindex(np.random.permutation(dataset.index))
```

Otherwise your biasing your test/train sets.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I didn't realize that the shuffling could be done through reindexing.  Cool.

Comment: @LarryFreeman, dont check with head on the new dataframe.. Head sorts on the index then displays... Drove me nuts for while.

Comment: If I don't check with head(), what's the alternative?

Comment: I wasnt clever I just used the above command in the Ipython notebook cell looked the top five... You could  look to slice with fancy indexing, I didnt try.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a new `Index` object directly to overwrite the index:

```
test.index = pd.Index(np.arange(len(df)), name='row_id')
```